# Problem with useEffect() on loading the page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having trouble with my react quiz app. Here follows the description:
This is from App.js file:

```
...
const [createQuiz, setCreateQuiz] = useState(false);
...
useEffect(()=> {
    const reRender = () => {
        setCreateQuiz(true)
    }
    window.onload=function(){
      document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", reRender);
    } 
    // return document.getElementById("myBtn").removeEventListener("click", reRender);
  }, [createQuiz])

return (
    <QuizContextProvider>
      {
      (createQuiz) ? (
        <div>Form</div>
      ) : (
        <div>
        <Modal/>
        <Question question={questions[questionNumber]} next={goToTheNext} />
        </div>
      )
      }
      {console.log(createQuiz)}
    </QuizContextProvider>
  );
}
```

As can be seen it is a conditional rendering: a Modal window asks a user whether they want to take the existing quiz or create their own and when the user clicks "Create your own " button, the app should re-render over again, this time the useEffect() (in App.js) sets the value of createQuiz to true. the code excerpt below is from `<Modal />` component:

```
return (
        <div className='benclosing' style={{display:displayValue}}>
        <div className='modal'>
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>
            <p>Do you want to take an existing quiz or create your own?</p>
            <button onClick={hideWindow} >Existing quiz</button>
            <button id='myBtn'>Create your own</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Everthing works fine as expected, except for 1: whenever reload icon is clicked, my page re-renders over-again and the user is again asked if they want to take the existing quiz. I want that refreshing affect nothing. I am stuck with this problem. How can I achieve the desired result?

I also tried this:

```
  const reRender = () => {
    setCreateQuiz(true)
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
    reRender()
    //return setCreateQuiz(false)

  }, [createQuiz])
```

It didn't work as expected. I described what it caused in my 2nd comment to Red Baron, please have a look.

Comment: just add some more state indicating if they user has clicked existing or create your own and then render the different html based off that?

Comment: I suppose this behaviour is because of ```window.onload```. I tried not to use it but then not having it an error saying "cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". That is why I am using  ```window.onload```.

Comment: you shouldn't need to use anything like that: `window.onload=function(){` you can call a function inside `useEffect` and it'll be called onload

Comment: @RedBaron Thank you! It nearly solved the problem! But after quitting the development server and starting again, ```<div>Form</div>``` appeared, not the ```<Modal/>```. This is another reason I feel induced to use ```window.onload```.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to achieve what you want is to create an event handler inside your `App` component that will set `createQuiz` to `true` when the `Create your own` button gets clicked inside the `Modal` component.

```
function App() {
  const [createQuiz, setCreateQuiz] = React.useState(false);

  const handleShowQuizForm = () => {
    setCreateQuiz(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {createQuiz ? (
        <div>Form</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Modal showQuizForm={handleShowQuizForm} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function Modal(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={props.showQuizForm}>
        Create your own
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's an example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/white-cache-ujcqs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

There's no need for the `useEffect` hook here and the `window.onload` event implies to me that you'd want to set `createQuiz` to `true` then "refresh" your page and expect `createQuiz` to now be `true` - it won't work like that.

Additionally, the way you're using the `useEffect` hook could be problematic - you should try to stay away from updating a piece of `state` inside of a `useEffect` hook that's also part of the `dependency array`:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const reRender = () => {
    setCreateQuiz(true);
  }
  // although not an issue here, but if this hook was
  // rewritten and looked like the following, it would
  // case an infinite re-render and eventually crash your app
  setCreateQuiz(!createQuiz);
}, [createQuiz]);
```